# starting vim with command substitution

Tags: bash, ls, wildcards, command-substitution

I am working on a project on two different machines - one running Mac OSX 10.8.3, and one running Red Hat Enterprise Linux. On my Mac, I can do this:

```
vim $(ls -R */*.@(h|cpp) */*/*.@(h|cpp))
```

and everything works fine. On the Linux box, it fails. All of these work exactly as I expect:

```
ls -R */*.@(h|cpp) */*/*.@(h|cpp)
echo $(ls -R */*.@(h|cpp) */*/*.@(h|cpp))
export myfilelist=$(ls -R */*.@(h|cpp) */*/*.@(h|cpp))
echo $myfilelist
```

But

```
vim $(ls -R */*.@(h|cpp) */*/*.@(h|cpp))
```

produces a set of mangled filenames, e.g.

```
^[[00m^[[00mevent_builder/include/eb_service.h^[[00m" [New DIRECTORY]
```

or

```
:ls
  1 %a   "^[[00m^[[00mevent_builder/include/eb_service.h^[[00m" line 1
  2      "^[[00mevent_builder/include/EventBuilder.h^[[00m" line 0
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: As Glenn points out, the `[[00m` stuff is ansi sequences used to color output on an ansi compatible terminal.  `ls --color=never` may help, see the man page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an alias (or function) for `ls` that colorizes the output. What does `type -a ls` give you? Instead use

```
vim $(command ls ...)
```

**However:** [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Try

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar
printf "%s\n" **/*.{h,cpp}
```

Comment: Ah, of course, colors. Great answer, thank you! (For the record, on my Mac, type -a ls = ls is aliased to `ls -Fh', and on the Linux box it is = ls is aliased to `ls -F --color')

Comment: @GabrielPerdue Fix your alias: make it `alias ls='ls -F --color=auto'`.